# Blog post "spams" feed

Tags: support, bug, android-app

When I refresh my feed in the stack exchange Android app, I'll get everytime a new blog post entry about stack overflows top navigation. That's annoying and I don't think it is how it should be.

[image]

App version: 1.0.89
Samsung Galaxy S5-mini
Android: 5.1.1

Comment: It's reproducing. Natural human behavior. ;)

Comment: Anyway, this is a bug, and it won't be fixed in the near future. (as any bug in the android app)

Comment: Why? Is the android app not supported anymore?

Comment: The developer can't work for personal reasons. For more details hit me in chat, better not discuss it in comments.